# Laravel belongsto relations get error SQLSTATE[42S22]

Tags: laravel

I get an error when calling $ event-> courts

"message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'courts.events_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `courts` where `courts`.`events_id` = 1 and `courts`.`events_id` is not null)",

Events

```
 <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Events extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'event_name',
        'frequency',
        'start_date',
        'end_date',
        'day',
        'session_time',
    ];

   
    public function scopeMy($query)
    {
        return $query->where('user_id', auth()->id());
    }

 
    public function courts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Court::class);
    }
}
```

Court

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Court extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'event_id',
        'name',
    ];

    public function event(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Events::class);
    }
}
```

Migration

Events

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->string('event_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('frequency')->nullable();
        $table->string('start_date')->nullable();
        $table->string('end_date')->nullable();
        $table->string('day')->nullable();
        $table->string('session_time')->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Courts

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('courts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->foreignId('event_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->string('name')->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm using tikner for now
php artisan tinker
$event = Events::find(1)
=> App\Models\Events {#4609
     id: 1,
     user_id: 3,
     event_name: "sda",
     frequency: "sada",
     start_date: "dad",
     end_date: "ada",
     day: "sda",
     session_time: "sda",
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
   }

 $event->courts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to mention your foreign key in the `Events` model relationship for the Court Model.

> Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key column for the Child model. By convention, Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the parent model and suffix it with _id.

your model name is `Events` and the foreign key is `event_id` in `Court` Model, singular and plural issue.
so change the relationship in `Events` model adding the second parameter

```
public function courts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Court::class, 'event_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change relation. You have to pass manually `foreignKey` and `ownerKey`

```
  public function event(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Events::class,'event_id','id');
    }
```

Then in court model also you need to  change

```
 public function courts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Court::class, 'event_id','id');
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately did not help (